# How to specify styles for individual classes in Dash Plotly?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to implement the following CSS into this Dash Plotly code.

```
.stats-list {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    flex:1;
    color:gray;
}
```

This is what I have so far for my Dash Plotly code

```
html.Div(className='body', children=[
    html.Ul(className='stats-list', children=[
        #A bunch of list items
    ]),
    html.Ul(className='stats-list', children=[
        #A bunch of list items
    ]),
    html.Ul(className='stats-list', children=[
        #A bunch of list items
    ])
])
```

What I don't want to do for each Unordered List is

```
html.Ul(className='stats-list', children=[
], style={
    'listStyle':'none',
    'padding':0,
    'flex':1,
    'color':gray #gray is a defined variable
})
```

Thank you in advance! :D

Answer (score 0):

Just [add your own CSS file](https://dash.plotly.com/external-resources) to the project, and define those CSS classes there.